# Core Audio: Working with Speaker, Is it possible to route to the internal speaker- AVAudioSessionPortBuiltInReceiver(Not to loud speaker)

Tags: ios, swift, core-audio, avaudiosession

As per the docs, Ther is no documentation about routing or even getting of the Port details for the "AVAudioSessionPortBuiltInReceiver". *(Note: Please read again, its not about this port `AVAudioSessionPortBuiltInSpeaker`)* .

As I found that and only possible `overrideOutputAudioPort` can be done only for

```
    public enum AVAudioSessionPortOverride : UInt {
    case None
    case Speaker
    }
```

**The Question is, Is ther any possibilities to play an audio through the :**

```
public let AVAudioSessionPortBuiltInReceiver: String /* The speaker you hold to your ear when on a phone call */
```

**Edit:**
Using `MPVolumeView` class(RouteButton) is listing out(routing to) of the AVAudioSessionPortBuiltInReceiver possible, Is it possible to achieve the same?.

Answer (score 3):

If you configure the audio session for play-and-record (and leave mix-with-others off), the default route on an iPhone becomes to play audio out the smaller ear speaker (not the louder speaker on the bottom), or out the plugged-in headset, if the user plugs a headset in.

Comment: Thanks for your response.   I used the same category but still its playing through the loud  speaker.

Comment: N do you know, Is ther any chance of getting the Port details of Built speakers when headset plugged in.

Answer (score 1):

Apple calls them "receiver" (i.e. top earpiece) and speaker.

to toggle between these two:

```
final private func changed(overrideNone: Bool) {

        let audioSession = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()
        var override : AVAudioSessionPortOverride = .none

        if overrideNone{
                color = UIColor.red
                override = .none
            }
            else{
                color = UIColor.yellow
                override = .speaker
            }

            self.view.backgroundColor = color

            do {
                    try audioSession.overrideOutputAudioPort(override)
            } catch _ {

            }   
        }
```

If You call with **false**, You will play via
override = .speaker

**so lower speaker.**

PS it does NOT work with iPads, as per june 2017 models..

Apple states:

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avaudiosessionportbuiltinreceiver

AVAudioSessionPortBuiltInReceiver (earpiece..)

Output to a speaker intended to be held near the ear.
..
Typically, this speaker is available only on iPhone devices.

(colors are for debug...)